# `$.each()` alternative in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loops

What is the alternative for jquery's `$.each()` loop in Angular JS.

I have got the following in jquery (in my Angular JS based project):

```
    $($scope.tasks).each(function(index, task){
        if (task.isCompleted) {
            task.showTask = true;
        }
    });
```

and I don't want to use the mix of jquery and angular, because they say it is a bad practice to do so (is it?). Is there any feature that angular provides like `$.each()`? Or should I go with the plain javascript?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [angular.forEach()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) for iterating in angularjs

```
angular.forEach($scope.tasks, function (task, index) {
    if (task.isCompleted) {
        task.showTask = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no need to mix those 2 if you don't want to... angular provides a skinned version of jQuery with basic selectors which is enough

Comment: He might be talking about outside a link function

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `Array.prototype.forEach` and shim it for old browsers using https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.

That way, you can do:

```
$scope.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
  if (task.isCompleted) {
    task.showTask = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`angular.forEach` does a great job for me. It provides brevity;

```
var newArr = [];
angular.forEach(oldArr, function (val, key) {
    this.push(someFunction(val, key)); // much wow
}, newArr);
```

But it depends from one use case to another. In most of the code I've written, it proves quite useful and it has completely replaced `$.each` for me.

About mixing things up, angular comes with a subset of jQuery methods that, in most cases, do the job and don't require anything else. I prefer keeping the application lightweight. Also, its a matter of principles for me to not mix things up with jQuery – since Angular is a completely different line of thought.